# Is this a hack? WordPress Usernames of every website we have changed into one single name automatically?

Tags: users, hacked

We host a lot of WordPress websites, today we noticed that almost every WordPress website we hosted changed their users' usernames into one single name, not only one user all the users of a website is changed into one single name but for some reason, the password is still not changed.

Is this a possible hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most definitely, all user names changed to admin I'm guessing ? I had this happen to an old website before. If available, I recommend recovering from a backup just in case they injected code in your posts / pages. I also recommend updating your plugins, templates and WordPress to the latest version and removing old unused plugins / templates.

Comment: We're now working on accessing the problem it looks like the damage is smaller than we thought, we'll consider taking your suggestions when the damage is accessed, Thank you very much.

Comment: if the only access you can get is via FTP you can add a new user via your themes function.php and change it to be an administrator (thats how I regained access)